# How to re-run a result back through a loop

Tags: excel, vba, loops, scheduling

I am scheduling medical exams, and need exclude public holidays from the scheduling process. How do reschedule the exams on public holidays to working days?

I have written code to schedule medical exams based on the current medical expiry date. I have then got a loop that checks if the scheduled date (Date 1) is a public holiday and reschedules (Date 2) if it is a public holiday. The problem I am having is that I cannot put the new date back into the start of the loop to check if it is also a public holiday.

```
    For p = 1 To UBound(PubHol)
        If MedDate(j, 1) = PubHol(p, 1) Then
            MedDate(j, 1) = ShiftMon(t - 2, ActCol)
        End If
    Next p
```

ShiftMon() is an array containing the available dates for scheduling.
ActCol is the active column within the array according to the persons shift.

MedDate() is run through the if statement to check if it matches any values in PubHol(). If it does, then it reschedules the person for the next earliest date that they are on shift (ShiftMon array: 't' is the row within the shift roster).

What I need is to run the new date (t-2) through the loop again to see if it is a public holiday and if so, reschedule to date 't-3'. This needs to happen until the scheduled date is not a public holiday.

Comment: Add your public holidays to a dictionary, `PubHol.Add Date, 1` then do the checking `PubHol.Exists(Date)` if it does, reschedule. More about dictionaries [here](http://www.snb-vba.eu/VBA_Dictionary_en.html)

Comment: Thanks Damian.

How do I go about adding a range of cells containing the public holiday dates to the dictionary instead of adding each date one at a time?

Or if I add an array (containing all the public holiday dates) to the dictionary, will it achieve the same result as adding them individually?

Comment: thing with arrays is that you need to loop through them to check if the date exists, instead dictionaries have a property, `.Exists` which will give you the answer without looping. You can loop through the range to add the holidays.

Comment: Grand! It worked out. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary to quickly test whether dates are public holidays. This is one type of implementation. Also note that the dictionary can be created in a less restricted scope so that the function doesn't always have to recreate the object.

```
Function Tester(dt As Date) As Date
    Dim oPubHol As Object
    Dim medDate As Date

    medDate = dt

    Set oPubHol = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    oPubHol.Add CDate("01/01/2019"), ""
    oPubHol.Add CDate("01/02/2019"), ""
    oPubHol.Add CDate("05/01/2019"), ""
    oPubHol.Add CDate("06/01/2019"), ""

    Do While oPubHol.exists(medDate)
        medDate = medDate - 1
    Loop

    Tester = medDate
End Function
```

RESULTS:

```
? tester(cdate("01/02/2019"))
12/31/2018 

? tester(cdate("05/02/2019"))
5/2/2019
```